# Why do polymorphic type synonyms not work like polymorphic data declarations in instances?

Tags: haskell

Vec2 is working as data declaration, but i try to scrap my boilerplate with tuples in this scenario:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

type Vec2 a = (a,a)

class Vector v where 
  foo :: v Integer

instance Vector Vec2 where 
  foo = (1,2)
```

Comment: You can't partially apply type synonyms: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2005-April/008340.html . In some cases, you can rewrite your type synonym to itself be partially applied - but in this case its impossible.

Comment: Include the error message.  Which, by the way, tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Type synonyms can't be partially applied. Since they are essentially type level functions, deciding equality between partially applied type synonyms is akin to deciding extensional equivalence.

You're well within your power to do something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance Foo String where
  ...
```

Since `String` is fully applied. There is a work around however, since types are curried, in some cases you can write things like

```
 type Arr = ((->) Int)
```

And create instances for this since the type synonym is "fully applied".

In this case clever eta conversion isn't possible so you're going to have to use a newtype,

```
newtype SimplePair a = SimplePair {unSimplePair :: (a, a)}
```